# How to connect Nikon D800 to Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, camera, mtp, ptp

(Nearly-new Ubuntu user here.)

What is the best way to connect my Nikon D800 to Ubuntu?

When I plug the USB cable into the computer, I get an error message saying

> Unable to mount NIKON DSC D800 Error initializing camera: -60: Could
>   not lock the device.

If I run lsusb, I get the following line:

```
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 04b0:042a Nikon Corp.
```

And if I launch the "Home Folder", I do see the camera listed under "Devices", and I can open the folders and see icons for the images, but they only load as thumbnails (they are RAW images).

I want to have Darktable directly import them, as it does perfectly with my Olympus E-PL2 camera. But Darktable insists that no supported devices were found.

The Nikon uses the MTP/PTP USB transfer method, while the Olympus uses mass storage. (I don't see any method for switching the Nikon to use mass storage).

Is there a way to get this to work? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Update: The solution, I found, is to un-mount the camera after it has been connected to the computer. To do this, call up the Home Folder, and right-click on the link to the Nikon camera. There's an option to un-mount it there.

Now to figure out how to stop Ubuntu from automatically mounting the camera.